# javascript regex mysteriously fails to match in Android 2.3 stock browser

Tags: javascript, android, regex

I have created a simple regex in javascript to parse a string and save what comes before the period in a string.  There is also the additional constraint that after the period must come one or more upper-case alphabetic characters:

```
var r=/([^.]*\.)[A-Z]+.*/gm
var col=r.exec(str)
```

Now I have no problems with this regex in mosts browser: Firefox, Chrome, etc.  However on an older browser (the stock browser for Android 2.3) I am getting mysterious failures which I don't understand.

```
"a.A1"  <- does not match in Android 2.3 stock browser
"A.A1"  <- does match
"a.B2"  <- does not match in Android 2.3 stock browser
"A.B2"  <- does match
"a1.A1" <- does not match in Android 2.3 stock browser
"a1.B2" <- does match
"a1.C2" <- does not match in Android 2.3 stock browser
```

I am at a loss to explain what is going on here.  If I understand my regex, it should match 0 or more characters which aren't a period, followed by a period, and this part it should capture.  Then it should continue matching one or more upper-case alphabetic characters after the period, followed by zero or more characters of any kind.   Why doesn't this match some of the examples above?

Comment: Can you try this regex: `var r = /([^.]*\.)[A-Z]+/;`

Comment: yes, that worked.  something about the `gm` suffix some browsers don't like?

Comment: See you aren't really using `g` OR `m` flags here so why even use them. `m` is for using `^ and $` in a multiline input and g is for global.

Comment: Using multi-line and global, wouldn't it be better written as `/^([^.]*\.)[A-Z]+.*$/` ? Otherwise the `[^.]*` will greedily match from the last newline to the next dot. If you don't need a global match, don't use it or multi-line, useing the same regex will validate the whole string.

Comment: @anubhava can you create an answer with this info, this solved my problem and i would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this regex:

```
var r = /([^.]*\.)[A-Z]+/;
```

You aren't really using `g` OR `m` flags here so why even use them. `m` is for using `^ and $`  in a multiline input and `g` is for global.

Also see this for possible cause of using global switch in Android 2.3.3 browser: https://github.com/f0r4y312/jquery-stylesheet/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your issue has to do with using the same regular expression multiple times with `.exec()` with the `g` flag.  When you do that, it keeps state (like the `.lastIndex` property) in the regular expression object for doing more than one match and that affects your next call to `.exec()` with that same regex.

If you aren't calling `.exec()` multiple times on the same string to find multiple matches, then remove the `g` flag from the regex to solve that issue.   If that isn't practical, then you may want to reset the `.lastIndex` property to 0 before calling your next match.